# How to include records with null associations that are being searched through?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have 3 models - Patient, User, CareGiver:

- Patient and CareGiver `has_one` User (stores name, email, etc.)
- CareGiver `belongs_to` Patient and Patients `has_many` CareGivers
- Some patients don't have CareGivers.

I'm trying to update a search query to allow us to search through a CareGiver's User attributes. The problem is that this search query tosses out any patients without a caregiver, which is undesired. Here's the search method:

```
def self.search(query)
  joins(:user, care_givers: :user)
  .where(
    %(users.first_name ILIKE :query OR
      users.last_name ILIKE :query OR
      users.email ILIKE :query OR
      CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) ILIKE :query OR
      users_care_givers.first_name ILIKE :query OR
      users_care_givers.last_name ILIKE :query OR
      users_care_givers.email ILIKE :query OR
      CONCAT_WS(' ', users_care_givers.first_name, users_care_givers.last_name) ILIKE :query),
      query: "%#{query}%"
  )
end
```

I've tried adding `care_givers.patient_id IS NULL OR` to the above query, but it has no effect.

`Patient.includes(:care_givers).where( care_givers: { patient_id: nil } )`

This query by itself works to grab patients without a caregiver, so how do I incorporate it into my search method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if `CareGiver` `has_one` `Patient` why do you have `care_givers.patiend_id` ?, the foreign key should be in `patients.care_giver_id` since it's the one with the `belongs_to` association.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for your comment. I incorrectly described the relationships. `CareGiver` `belongs_to` `Patient` and `Patient` `has_many` `CareGivers`

Comment: should that be `joins(:user, care_givers: :patient)` ?

Comment: anyway, are you using Rails 5 ?, if so then you need to use `left_outer_joins` instead of `joins` take a look at the docs to check how to use it. Basically you need to do a `LEFT JOIN` to "let" pass the ones that do not have a "join" record.

Comment: I'm using rails 4, but what you're saying makes sense. The query `Patient.includes(:care_givers).where( care_givers: { patient_id: nil } )` generates SQL that contains a LEFT JOIN:

`FROM "patients" LEFT OUTER JOIN "care_givers" ON "care_givers"."patient_id" = "patients"."id" AND "care_givers"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE "care_givers"."patient_id" IS NULL`

I'll poke around some more. Thanks for the suggestion!